# Финализированные переменные

Tags: java

Когда можно инициализировать final переменную?
Может ли final переменная быть аргументом метода?
Есть ли у final переменной значение по умолчанию?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

По порядку:

**1.** **Когда можно инициализировать final переменную?**

Можно проинициализировать сразу

```
public class Test {
    private final int i = 8;
}
```

Можно в конструкторе (если эта переменная не static)

```
public class Test {
    private final int i;

    public Test(int i) {
        this.i = i;
    }
}
```

А можно в блоке инициализации (static переменная в static блоке, non-static - в non-static)

```
public class Test {
    private static final int i1;
    private final int i2;

    static {
        i1 = 8;
    }
    {
        i2 = 8;
    }
}
```

**2. Может ли final переменная быть аргументом метода?**

Может. Значение данной переменной нельзя будет изменить внутри самого метода (см. пример)

```
class Demo {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int i = 10;
        method(i);
        i = 12; // <- можно изменить занчение, т. к. i не final
    }

    public static void method(final int i) {
        i = 11; // <- нельзя изменить значение здесь, т. к. 
                // аргумент передается с модификатором final
    }
}
```

**3. Есть ли у final переменной значение по умолчанию?**

Нет. Значение должно быть задано вручную (см. п. 1)

Comment: Валентин, огромное спасибо за то, что просто и понятно все объяснили!